# Troubleshooting noisy FET buffer for contact mic

Tags: audio, impedance-matching, troubleshooting, piezo, preamp

I'm trying to follow the schematic on [this page](https://www.zachpoff.com/diy-resources/alex-rice-piezo-preamplifier/) to create a preamp/impedance matcher for a balanced piezo contact mic. I've reproduced the schematic below.

[image]

I've built it on a breadboard and I'm finding that the output is at least 20dB *below* that of the contact mic on its own, and has considerable noise. I'm finding it difficult diagnosing this, not having very in depth electrical engineering knowledge myself. I wonder if someone could suggest the likeliest causes?

My JFETs are 2N3819, matched by hand using the technique suggested on that page. My R3 is 1K, and my R1,R2,R5,R6 are 3M3 (easier to source). My capacitors are polypropylene, rated for 100V, and all resistors are carbon.

Possible problems:

- My JFET matching went wrong. I gather that unmatched JFETs would result in noise, but would they also result in a signal drop where there should be gain?
- The assumptions the circuit design makes about the internal architecture of my audio interface are wrong, ie. *"It takes advantage of the fact that phantom power is fed to the balanced XLR inputs via pair of closely matched 6.81k resistors. These resistors are used directly as the drain resitors in the differential amplifier rather than the more usual method of connecting an additional pair of matched resistors to each line to create a +48V supply rail and then feeding the signal back through DC blocking capacitors. Since the mixing desk already blocks DC at it’s inputs it’s not a problem that the signal is floating at +45V or so."*
- Some of my component selections were wrong: an exact 3M value is critical, or the resistors should be metal film.

Many thanks for all help and suggestions.

**EDIT:** Here's a photo of my current breadboard setup in case there are any glaring mistakes.
[image: preamp breadboard]

Comment: A quick check with a multimeter will tell you if the +48V is present... There is usually a switch to enable it on the audio interface / mixing desk.

Comment: I have indeed turned +48V on. Without it I don't hear anything.

Comment: OK, did you check the voltage on tail current setting resistor R3? Also the points XLR2, XLR3 on your schematic should be 48V - half of current through R3 times soundcard output resistance which is probably 6k8. So a little bit below 48V.

Comment: Note carbon resistors are noisy and very inaccurate. Where did you find carbon resistors? This warrants checking the voltage between Q1/Q2 gates. It should be quite small. Imbalance in the 3M resistors could cause one of the FETs to turn off and then the whole thing no longer works...

Comment: Ok, I'm measuring ~16.3V for the XLR terminals, and 0 across R3 (Though I don't quite get why I would expect to find a voltage there. Am I understanding where you're suggesting to measure?) I did subsequently read that carbon resistors are not ideal for audio applications, and so I was intending to replace them before I soldered it together, but I didn't think they'd make it break down altogether. So R1, R2, R5, R6 should be matched to within more than 5%?

Comment: Well, no voltage across R3 is your problem... Q3 and R3 make a constant current sink which biases the other transistors, so if there is no current there, it won't work. Maybe a bad connection on your breadboard? As for the 4 3Meg resistors, if they are old carbon composition (are those even still made?) watch out for accuracy, the old ones can drift a lot...

Comment: 16.3V on teh XLR pins means 32V dropped across 3.4K ( two 6k8's in parallel) which suggests nearly 10mA through the FETs ... good ... BUT that should pass through R3. Something very wrong there as Peufeu says. Q3 blown or miswired?

Comment: I rewired the circuit after realising that I had the source and drain on the FETs backwards (The result of a misleading image found on Google. Lesson: always stick to the datasheet). I'm now measuring 47.4V on XLR pins, 61mV between Q1/Q2 gates, still 0 across R3. Additionally I'm now hearing a low fluttering in the output signal. I've tried swapping out Q3, flipping it... No luck...

Comment: @Igid - If you see this, can you add an update of the status, please? Did you eventually solve the problem and, if so, how? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson I'm afraid I abandoned the project. I hope you find any answers you need though!

Comment: @Igid - Many thanks for the update. I was asking on behalf of user [*Isaac Raimundo*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/258010/isaac-raimundo) who doesn't yet have the "reputation points" needed to write comments, and tried to ask you this question in their answer (which is generally not allowed). So now they know :-) Thanks again!

Comment: these breadboard setups can be pretty unreliable. I would check for +48V actually on the D of Q1/2 and then for 24V on their gates

Answer (score 0):

The first time I've built a high impedance microphone circuit I thought it was malfunctioning, but then found that it had to be put inside a shielded enclosure.

Comment: Welcome to the site :-) However, unlike typical internet forums, Stack Exchange sites have different places for questions & answers. You generally shouldn't ask a *question* in an *answer*, so I removed that part. When you reach 50 points, you will be able to write a *comment* (which is where you would be allowed to ask about project status etc). So I have asked your question in a comment on your behalf, and the OP has kindly replied - see above.

Answer (score -2):

The inverting feedback on each FET, from drain-to-gate, allows a gain of TWO.

Time constant on each gate is 1.5MegOhm * 220pF = 330uS, or 500 Hertz corner in that HIGH PASS FILTER. Thus your bass tones and midrange are strongly attenuated.

Comment: How are these comments relevant? The circuit is designed expressly to remedy the HPF caused by impedence mismatch, and I can only conclude that there must be something wrong in your reasoning in regard to that.